# Vue/Vuetify: why am I getting a ReferenceError: variable is not defined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating the client side of a web app in Vuetify and have a node.js server with some data on it. On the page, I have details being shown with an expansion-panel, like so:

```html
  <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <p>Total Computers Online: {{card.comps}}</p>
    <p>Total Users On Computers(Online and in Person): {{card.users}}</p>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
```

In my data where the information in cards is coming from looks like this

```
 data() {
  return {
      makEosComputer: 0,
      makEosUserTotal: 0,
      makArchComputer: 0,
      makArchUserTotal: 0,
      makDataComputer: 0,
      makDataUserTotal: 0,
      cards: [
        {title: 'Eos Lab', comps: makEosComputer, users: makEosUserTotal},
        {title: 'Arch Lab', comps: makArchComputer, users: makArchUserTotal},
        {title: 'Data Comm Lab', comps: makDataComputer, users: makDataUserTotal}
      ],
  }
  },
```

The variables that all start with "mak" are having their data being pulled from the node.js server in methods below and that data is being put into the corresponding variable. When I try to run this however, I get "ReferenceError: makEosComputer is not defined". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are missing `this`, it should be for example `this.makEosComputer`.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo oh my, such a simple mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable needs to be declared *beforehand* (not in the same object):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    const makEosComputer = 0
    const makEosUserTotal = 0
    const makArchComputer = 0
    const makArchUserTotal = 0
    const makDataComputer = 0
    const makDataUserTotal = 0

    return {
      makEosComputer,
      makEosUserTotal,
      makArchComputer,
      makArchUserTotal,
      makDataComputer,
      makDataUserTotal,
      cards: [
        {title: 'Eos Lab', comps: makEosComputer, users: makEosUserTotal},
        {title: 'Arch Lab', comps: makArchComputer, users: makArchUserTotal},
        {title: 'Data Comm Lab', comps: makDataComputer, users: makDataUserTotal}
      ],
    }
  }
}
```